# How to get the port name of a print job in a printer pooling scenario

Tags: c#, delphi, winapi, printing, spooler

In the windows -> printers and devices -> actual print queue  there is (the last) column called Port [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBRWx.png)

When printer pooling is enabled, this shows the port name (for the real printer) the document is printing like first c:\ports\p1, second c:\ports\p2 (or port_2121 and port_2122 ... etc).
I want to get the same information.

I checked [Enumjobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162625(v=vs.85).aspx) , and JOB_INFO_1 - 4 structure, non of them has a port or portname member. 
I tested, and pPrinterName is always the same too. So not even from that side it is accessible.

Any idea how could I get the port where the job is printing ? (like the print queue does)

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `FindNextPrinterChangeNotification` function with `JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_PORT_NAME` field. This value can be changed when printer pooling is enabled and one port is buzy